# Searching ListBox control and programmatically selecting closest match

Tags: c#, search, listbox

I have a ListBox control populated with branches of a large retail chain. The staff using the system have to log in to the relevant branch, and I would like them to be able to search the ListBox to find their branch.

I have created an event handler for when text in the search box changes, and attempted to use code sound on StackOverflow already:

```
private int lastMatch = 0;

private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 0;
        string match = txtSearch.Text;

        if (txtSearch.Text.Length != 0)
        {
            bool found = true;
            while (found)
            {
                if (lbBranches.Items.Count == x)
                {
                    lbBranches.SetSelected(lastMatch, true);
                    found = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    lbBranches.SetSelected(x, true);
                    match = lbBranches.SelectedValue.ToString();
                    if (match.Contains(txtSearch.Text))
                    {
                        lastMatch = x;
                        found = false;
                    }
                    x++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I compile and start typing into the search box, I get this error:

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

The line in question is:

```
match = lbBranches.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

I have no idea what could be wrong there, anyone got an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Typically, that error means you're attempting to reference the property of a null object. In the line given, either `lbBranches` or its `SelectedValue` property appears to be null. Hard to tell, from the code given, why that would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SelectedValue of the listbox will only return a value if you have specified the ValueMember property of the listbox to indicate a property from which you would like to read the value for the selected item.  The property you want to use in this case is SelectedItem:

```
match = lbBranches.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Comment: Cheers, that worked. Now I just have to work out why it isn't selecting the right item :p

Comment: Based on what I see in your code, it will match the first one it finds that meets the contains criteria and exit the loop, so if you only have a short list of characters in the textbox, it could appear to be matching the incorrect one.  I agree with Hardyv that you should look at using a dropdown that allows for type ahead.

Answer (score 0):

when the user is entering text it's possible that no value has been selected (hence the error) -- keep in mind that what is being entered by the user has no mandatory or direct association with selections in the controls listbox sub-element

it's possible what you're doing might be simpler to implement with a full combo-box control and I think some of the examples at MSDN could be very helpful for you as well